# Why can't I delete column/ field from imported CSV in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, merge

I merged the df you see below in another file, and when I imported it into the current file, I was met with a strange field, 'Unnamed: 0', that I hadn't seen before. It wasn't there back.

I have listed the column names, copied the field name exactly, and attempted to drop it but was unsuccessful.

[image]

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `df.drop` does not work in place, unless you ask it to.  By default, it returns a new dataframe, which you discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Always use inplace = True when you are changing something in place in a dataframe or try to store in the different dataframe like this if you are not changing the source dataframe,

```
new_df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_data+file_name, sep=',')
columns_to_drop = [column for column in df.columns if 'Unnamed:' in column]
df.drop(columns_to_drop, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```